# sorting a list within a list in java

Tags: java, list, collections

I have the below code

```
List<List1<String, String>> list1_a = Readafile(filename);
```

the data in the file is as follows

```
value 1    value 2        rank
      a    b              1
      a    c              2
      d    e              1
      d    c              4
```

I need to sort the list1_a according to the rank

i tried the below:
`Collections.sort(list1_a)`, but im no teven able to understand the error it is throwing me.
Update:
below is the error description:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<List1<String,String>>). The 
 inferred type List1<String,String> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Comment: we're not able to understand the error since you didn't post it! :)

Comment: is List1 your custom class?

Comment: make your List1 class implement compareable List1<String, String> and make your sorting there.

Comment: do List1 hold key value pair?

Comment: @AlpeshGediya it has a rank that is the value, im not able to understand what the key is, im totally new to java and collections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that `Collections.sort(List<T>)` ony accepts objects `T` which implement `Comparator` or `Comparable<T>`, Which is not the case of `List1<String,String>` (in `List<List1<String,String>>`, `T` is a `List1<String,String>`)

You can create a comparator of `List1<String,String>`; (i.e. a class which implements `Comparator<List1<String,String>>`) like this

```
public class YourComparator implements Comparator<List1<String,String>>{

  public int compare(List1<String,String> o1, List1<String,String> o2){
    //implement this method
  }

}
```

then sort your collection like this:

```
Collections.sort(list1_a, new YourComparator());
```

Comment: Correct in principle, but note the problem didn't involve a `List<List<String>>` but a `List<List1<String,String>>`. It's not clear from the question how `List1` is defined, but that is the type you have to instantiate the `Comparator` with.

Comment: That's right. I updated, thanks.